# Why does test suite for smart home run out of time

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

With regards to the test suite, I've entered the userAgentId and the json key correctly and it progresses fine. It's when I start the test where the problem arises. Each utterance is read out to my Google Home. The Google Home wakes up to the "Ok Google. Turn off the colorful light ". The colorful light are off and reported the close status to the home graph. I link to the reportstate dashboard to confirm quickly that the status has been modified. After I waited a long time and finally got a timeout error. I don't know why and what else I need to do? I have two screenshots here. One is the request timeout and the other is the reportstatus dashboard.

[timeout pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93guG.png)

[reportstate dashboard of my colorful light](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGniO.png)

Comment: Do you see any common errors (as in https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/tools/smart-home-test-suite#error_messages)  in the stack driver console?

You can find more info about Smart Home actions logging here: https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/monitoring-logging#logging

Comment: I read the link you gave, but there is no solution to this problem. Similarly, I checked the Smart Home actions logging. There is no content in the smart home actions logging. My application is deployed on my own server and the server has output execution records.

Comment: No errors in your own server logs?

Comment: Can you give an example of an `EXECUTE` request you received and the execution response payload you returned? (for the failure you mentioned)

Answer (score 1):

Timeouts with the test suite can be due to the following reason:

--The execution or query responses might be failing, or taking too much time.

--Report State implementation might be faulty.

The report state dashboard is an old tool that is not maintained anymore, hence the changes you see there might not represent what’s written to the homegraph accurately. Instead, can you try out using the HomeGraph Viewer.